# Cast string to number, format; unless cannot be cast, then string=string

Tags: swift, casting, conditional-statements

The variable `benefit.amount` comes in as a String.

```
var amount = String()
if let tempAmount = benefit.amount as? NSDecimalNumber {
    amount = Formatter.currencyFormat(tempAmount)
} else {
    amount = tempAmount
}
```

All I am trying to do is if the `benefit.amount` is something like `1000`, that I can use the currency formatter on it.  Sometimes though that variable may look something like `Included in Policy Year Maximum Benefit`, which clearly cannot be made into a number.

Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

Just try to convert the value to `Int`. The initializer returns `nil` on failure.

```
let amount : String
if let tempAmount = Int(benefit.amount) {
    amount = Formatter.currencyFormat(tempAmount)
} else {
    amount = benefit.amount
}
```

Comment: If you try to convert an amount like "1.23" then the `Int` init method will fail. Using a `Float` is problematic because decimal numbers aren't stored well in the internal binary format and you often won't get the same value as what you started with. `NSDecimalNumber` is intended to store base-10 numbers accurately.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the `init(string:)` method and compare the result against `NSDecimalNumber.notANumber()`:

```
let decimal = NSDecimalNumber(string: benefitAmount)
if decimal == NSDecimalNumber.notANumber() {
  // handle not a number
}
else {
  // handle the number
}
```